how to solve this limit or show it does not exist?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^2\cos(y)}{x^2+y^4}$$
I tried doing it using the Squeeze Theorem, and the equation I got using that was
$\frac{xy^2\cos(y)}{x^2 +y^4} \leq \frac{xy^2}{x^2 +y^4}.$
I don't know how to proceed further.

Take limits on different paths to see what happens

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^{2}\cos(y)}{x^{2}+y^{4}}$. Take the curve $\alpha(t) = (t^{2},t)$
We have that $\lim_{t\to 0} f(\alpha(t)) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t^{4}\cos(t)}{2t^{4}} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\cos(t)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$.
On the other hand, if we take the curve $\beta(t) = (t,t)$, we have that
$\lim_{t\to 0} f(\beta(t)) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^{3}\cos(t)}{t^{2}+ t^{4}} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t\cos(t)}{1+t^{2}} = 0$
Then the limit does not exist because it takes different values depending on the curve along which you approach $(0,0)$.
